# how to set serial port depth in delphi

Tags: delphi, serial-port

does anyone know if it's possible to set the size of windows input buffer assigned to a serial port in delphi? this parameter can be accessed in device manager->serial port->port settings->advanced, with max of 4K for my win8.1 usb port, while MS article says it can be 31-bit:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readbuffersize(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: How are you creating the serial port?  Directly via WinAPI?  Using a component? (If so, which one?).  Which version of Delphi?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363423(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: i use createfile, setcommstate, setcommtimeouts. delphi is 2010.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz seems setupcomm function works (returns true), although i haven't verified the settings are actually written, yet. thanks, i guess this might be the solution.

Comment: @mio it's very possible that the device driver is ignoring the request, verify with GetCommProperties.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz i just tested this and got a strange result. upon setting both rx and tx to a number <4K, getcommproperties reports  dwMaxRxQueue=0, dwMaxTxQueue=0, dwCurrentRxQueue=4096, dwCurrentTxQueue=0. if i set both with a number >4K, i get this number back as CurrentRxQueue, and three other fields are zero again. i presume the currentRx is the field i should check. do first two zeroes mean that the device has infinite max? why is currentTx zero, does that mean i can't control it?

Comment: To avoid speculation, wrong guesses, multiple q/a comments and possible misundestandings, please show your actual setup code and the full result of `GetCommProperties()` as an edit to your question (see the "edit" button beneath the tags).